# Is there a way create a service object of an NUnit test class to use dependency injection when connecting it to a console app?

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, dependency-injection, appium-android

I have an NUnit3 project and a console app project in .NET 5 and would like to be able to use dependency injection for a class in my NUnit project. In the console app I am creating the HostBuilder to configure the services for the dependency injection, but in the Main method when I am trying to get the service object of my test class it is returning null. I am not too familiar with DI other than a couple small ASP.NET projects I've done so I don't know if I am doing this right exactly or if this is something that can be done. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
namespace SeleniumTest
{
    public interface IDriverHelper
    {
        public AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> Driver { get; }
    }
}
```

```
namespace SeleniumTest
{
    public class DriverHelper : IDriverHelper
    {

        private AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver;
        private AppiumLocalService appiumLocalService;
        private AppiumOptions appiumOptions;

        public AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> Driver
        {
            get => driver;
            set
            {
                appiumLocalService = new AppiumServiceBuilder().UsingAnyFreePort().Build();
                appiumLocalService.Start();

                appiumOptions = new AppiumOptions();
                // options added here

                driver = new AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>(appiumLocalService, appiumOptions);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the beginning of the Test Class

```
namespace SeleniumTest
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class Tests
    {
        private readonly IDriverHelper _driverHelper;

        public MyMerlin(IDriverHelper driverHelper)
        {
            _driverHelper = driverHelper;
        }
```

In the code below, `var test = host.Services.GetService<Tests>();` returns null so I am unable to run any of the tests in that class, ex: `test.PreSetupTest();`

```
public class Program
    {
        static Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

            using IHost host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();

            var test = host.Services.GetService<Tests>();
            test.PreSetupTest();

            return host.RunAsync();
        }
        static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureServices((_, services) =>
                    services.AddSingleton<IDriverHelper, DriverHelper>());
    }
```

Comment: Why do you need the test class from your console application? Did you try registering the class like you do with `DriverHelper` (`services.AddSingleton<Tests>()`)?

Comment: Thank you @Xerillio, that worked. The finished program will be a console app that uses those tests so I wanted to run them from it. I hadn't done unit tests before this, so it kind of went over my head that the unit test project wouldn't be part of the published projects when it's all said and done.